# WF4 - Rehosted Workflow Designer - Readonly View with Enabled PropertyInspectorView

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, designer, workflow-rehosting

I wrote an application that re-hosts the Workflow 4 Designer (System.Activities.Presentation.WorkflowDesigner) as well as displays the PropertyInspectorView to allow for modification of activity parameters.  What I would like to do is disable the designer view from modifications (can't drop new activities on it, reorder it, delete activities, etc.) but still leave the property view editable when the user highlights an activity.  Basically I want to be able to deploy drawn but un-configured workflows, and have somebody else fill in the activity arguments.

Every solution I've tried disables the entire designer and property view.  I've tried setting IsEnabled to false on the View as well as setting the ReadOnlyState.IsReadOnly to true.

Any ideas on how I can achieve this behavior?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. WorkflowDesigner control has no such feature. I need to to it this way:

```
_Wd = new WorkflowDesigner();

//Setting WorkflowDesigner

_Wd.View.PreviewDragEnter += View_PreviewDrop;
_Wd.View.PreviewDrop += View_PreviewDrop;
_Wd.View.PreviewKeyDown += View_PreviewKeyDown;

void View_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

void View_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```